# Android Cmake 3.18.1 configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, boost, cmake, build.gradle

How to setup CMake 3.18.1 in an Android project with gradle on Android Studio?
I executed the following steps:

1. downloaded the CMake 3.18.1 from Android Sdk - Sdk Tools (folder appeared correctly on Android/sdk/cmake with the 3.10 and 3.6 version)
2. I added the version requested on build.gradle as  `externalNativeBuild { cmake { version "3.18.1"`
3. I added the path on local.properties as `cmake.dir=/Users/bloom/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.18.1`

I get the error message: `C/C++ release|armeabi-v7a : CMake '3.18.1' found via cmake.dir='/Users/bloom/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.18.1' does not match requested version '3.10.2'.` and the task failed is `> Task :app:generateJsonModelDebug FAILED`

I suspect there is a 3.10 version hardcoded somewhere, maybe on that task. In fact, undoing point 3 and requesting version 3.6 is ignored. With 3.10 I get an error on findBoost and it clearly shows that is using the 3.10 version, as you can see `Make Warning at /Users/bloom/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:567 (message):`